# Max USB current on a Pi Zero V1.3

Tags: usb-power, pi-zero

Whats the maximum current I get out of the USB port of the Pi Zero? I'd like to power USB Speakers (5V 3W). Is that possible?

Comment: as far as I can find, the USB max current is 600mA

Comment: I did use cheap (0.50$) PAM8403 Stereo Audio Amplifier to output on 89 dB 8 Ω 3W loudspeakers ... [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkCPt9qR_n4), [forum thread](http://www.friendlyarm.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=264&p=794#p794)

Answer (score 2):

For the Pi2 the current limit is 0.6 A. (Don't know the specs of the Zero, but i think it is also around that level) Thats what your Speaker uses. So it MAY work.
I would just try it. What is the worst thing that could happen? Fuse would turn the Pi off, you unplug the speaker, fuse would reset and the Raspberry Pi would reboot.

If it does not work, maybe try `max_usb_current=1` in the `/boot/config.txt`. That changes the Maximum USB current to 1.2 A. Then you should have enough power.

Comment: This was useful, why is it not the accepted answer?